# Is there a tool to get the IP of a domain?

Tags: ip, domain, domain-name

I have changed the A record of my domain, but now I don't know how to test if I can see the change. Is there a tool that I can use to determine the IP given a domain name, that I can  use?

I don't want these online tools, I want to run it from my machine... so that I know that the IP changed from my point of view.

Comment: These types of questions are better suited for SuperUser.com

Comment: I don't know about it being a SU question as such. It might be basic but there's nothing at all wrong with that and it's a valid query for a sysadmin to have.

Comment: What operating system? And why didn't you add this to your question considering you are asking for an application to run on your client machine?

Comment: @PP Didn't think about that... I'm running Windows 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no end of tools around for testing how DNS settings are seen from the outside world. I've used [DNSStuff](http://www.dnsstuff.com/) in the past, but there are lots out there. The biggest test of course is whether or not you get complaints from customers about the site being down, and this can still happen because of cached info on their local DNS or other similar issues regardless of what the tests might say.

If you want to test from your local machine's point of view then [nslookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup) or [dig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dig_%28command%29) will work. Windows supports nslookup, and most unixes will support one or the other, or even both.

[image: nslookup on windows example]

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I found that there is a problem with a CNAME entry that I changed, but I cannot see the change yet, it is taking a lot of time to update. I can see the correct A value though. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that my comments about caching can apply on a local LAN too - clients may also cache DNS responses...

Answer (score 1):

I like dig:

```
$ dig any example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-rl.028.23-P2-RedHat-9.9.2-10.P2.fc18 <<>> any example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52655
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 7, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.           IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        170658  IN  RRSIG   A 8 2 172800 20130621152841 20130614072746 49830 example.com. P/s7wWdRocK76xcMjHQUvKlxJw0Hh52wkDseFi0W+PQ9ZUrRWSKOWBHH 4g+prSs3fG/PusGnhFUNNQx//KsIiSDQgJExw66rUsBf1IrTgSrGgCDC 1D84fTiLKi3hUIITDw2FaQEzAzjrbpR2MT+huXey+S20UWLFJAwqRHK9 sMA=
example.com.        170658  IN  A   192.0.43.10
example.com.        13272   IN  RRSIG   DS 8 2 86400 20130618042035 20130611031035 35519 com. dHr8vFmY6mkpvzrXS/9zYeYuZ2h8a4iSkVoftFIkyDRipqtK9rnsxVLF kRE8aantCDnHFSbPL3ScqD2HmsBByBZ6VoqHiJpmaO1ktvmaw5KGPMpA J5DV8Ng4t7WPe0qxTU1xzmFNhTc/ZEzYpZfOCSVRXer7VI5KYl2QsHN+ +Nw=
example.com.        13272   IN  DS  31589 8 2 CDE0D742D6998AA554A92D890F8184C698CFAC8A26FA59875A990C03 E576343C
example.com.        13272   IN  DS  31589 8 1 3490A6806D47F17A34C29E2CE80E8A999FFBE4BE
example.com.        99672   IN  NS  b.iana-servers.net.
example.com.        99672   IN  NS  a.iana-servers.net.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.        99672   IN  NS  b.iana-servers.net.
example.com.        99672   IN  NS  a.iana-servers.net.

;; Query time: 67 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.88.1#53(192.168.88.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Jun 14 12:20:35 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 539
```